# Json to Java Object with same key but different objects inisde

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a question how to map JSON Objects with same key to different objects.
If I write 2 classes with the specific fields I get an error because the data element is contained twice.

How can I map the resource A to class A and the resource B to class B?

```
{
   "ETag":"oiojojojojoj==",
   "elements":[
      {
         "resource":"A",
         "ETag":null,
         "data":[
            {
               "anotherfield":"text",
               "id":1,
               "name":"GB"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "resource":"B",
         "ETag":"dmVuZG9yOzIwMTctMDUtMDlUMTQ6MzE6NDNa",
         "data":[
            {
               "field":"read",
               "id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The classes could look like this:

```
public class Element {
    @JsonProperty("resource")
    public String resource = null;
    @JsonProperty("ETag")
    public Object eTag = null;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<A> dataInA = null;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<B> dataInB = null;
}

public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("ETag")
    public String eTag;
    @JsonProperty("elements")
    public List<Element> elements = null;

}
```

**Class A**

```
public class A {

    @JsonProperty("anotherfield")
    public String anotherfield;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B {

    @JsonProperty("field")
    public String field;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer id;

}
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

When I switch the JSON elements to dataA and dataB It works.

```
{
   "ETag":"oiojojojojoj==",
   "elements":[
      {
         "resource":"A",
         "ETag":null,
         "dataA":[
            {
               "anotherfield":"text",
               "id":1,
               "name":"GB"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "resource":"B",
         "ETag":"dmVuZG9yOzIwMTctMDUtMDlUMTQ6MzE6NDNa",
         "dataB":[
            {
               "field":"read",
               "id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Element class:**

```
public class Element {

    @JsonProperty("resource")
    public String resource;
    @JsonProperty("ETag")
    public Object eTag;
    @JsonProperty("dataA")
    public List<A> dataInA;
    @JsonProperty("dataB")
    public List<B> dataInB;

}
```

Comment: show a stacktrace with the error

Comment: This is all I can see: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Duplicate creator property "data" (index 2 vs 3)]

Comment: `@JsonProperty("data")` occurring twice -- isn't it wrong? Try `@JsonProperty("dataInA")` and `@JsonProperty("dataInB")` or whatever proper property names.

Comment: Yes, but I can't change the Json structure